# Macro to export Visio shape texts to Excel

Tags: excel, text, export, visio

This solution cannot be recommended as Visio's report functionality exports more texts than this macro. That said, the code below works.

```
    Sub ExportVisioTextsExcel()
 
    Dim vsPage As Visio.Page
    Dim vsDoc As Visio.Document
    Dim xlApp, xlWB, xlWS, vsApp As Object
    Dim FldPath As String

   
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set vsApp = CreateObject("Visio.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = True
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    Set vsDoc = vsApp.Documents.Open("C:\xyz\File.vsdx")
    FldPath = "C:\xyz\"
 
    For Each vsPage In vsDoc.Pages
        Set xlWS = xlWB.Sheets.Add(After:=xlWB.Worksheets(xlWB.Worksheets.Count))
        ShapesList vsPage.Shapes, xlWS
    Next vsPage
   
    xlWB.SaveAs FldPath & "xxx" & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD")
   
    MsgBox "Texts exported", vbInformation
   
End Sub
 
Sub ShapesList(ByVal shps As Shapes, ByVal xlWS As Object)
    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim vChars As Visio.Characters
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = xlWS.Cells(xlWS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   
    For Each sh In shps
        If sh.Shapes.Count = 0 Then
            If Not sh.OneD Then
                Set vChars = sh.Characters
                xlWS.Cells(lRow, 1).Value = sh.ID
                xlWS.Cells(lRow, 2).Value = sh.Name
                xlWS.Cells(lRow, 3).Value = vChars.Text
            lRow = lRow + 1
            End If
        End If
        ShapesList sh.Shapes, xlWS
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Thanks to @PaulHerber, @Surrogate and @wapperdude at http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?PHPSESSID=76f6964e4d1518f3495af46e92c2a609&topic=10128.0

Comment: What do you mean as `text box` ?

Comment: Text boxes are just normal shapes but with no border. Are you sure none of your shapes are grouped, because your code doesn't deal with grouped shapes.

Comment: Oh yes, and another thing. If your shape text consists of fields then the .Text method doesn't return that.

Comment: Aha! Thank you @Paul Herber - I am new to Visio so grouping never occured to me as a factor! Yes, they are grouped. Will work on that!

Comment: I have added CreateSelection to select all groups including subgroups in the page, but this only ungroups the first shape in the first page. I now get the Text from that subgroup, so that part works. But how do I expand this to ungroup all subgroups in all pages?

Answer (score 3):

CreateSelection will not identify and select group childshapes.  It takes a recursive algorithm to step down into a group and any subsequent groups therein.

Stepping thru the posted code,

1. the select all line traps every top level shape and only top level shapes.
2. the next line groups those shapes
3. the ungroup line ungroups all of the top level shapes.  If there were additional groups within any of the top level objects, those are not ungrouped.

Ungrouping is not a recommended procedure as smart shapes can be broken.  Also, links to a master shape will be broken.

A working solution with Visio test file posted here: http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=10128.msg46806#msg46806.  This solution does not use ungrouping and is non-destructive.